# I an not able to run the emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I am not able to run the emulator in android studio for java app and also for the flutter app. I have tried almost everything but I don't know why it is not working.

Can anyone help me to run the emulator.

When Trying to run the Java app:
[The Top Bar of My Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtu1x.png)

[I am getting this thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuVOG.png)

When I try to run the flutter app in Android Studio, I am getting this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXYuD.png)

And When I run `flutter doctor` I am getting these errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twJWI.png)

Comment: Please describe any error messages you are seeing, otherwise we cannot really help you.

Comment: Ok When I run the flutter app I get the error: Error Running 
Target Device

Answer (score -1):

Android Emulator requires a lot of memory space so, in most cases, it doesn't work for any of the reasons.
So I also have left from the android studio emulator and choose for the best alternative one and that is menu emulator.
It runs on any of the memory size PC or laptop.
But it runs smoothly on more than 8GB RAM.
And I also use this.